# Could a web server be an actor in use case diagram of an offline android app?

Tags: uml

there is android app which collect  some data that a user enter in to application 
, when it accesses the internet  it send data to server , could web server be an actor in use case diagram ?

Answer (score 1):

Actor is always **external** to the system.

If the server is a part of the system then no.
If the server is an external system - then this system (but not a server as such) might be your actor.

As I understand your question the server is a part of your system thus it will not be visible on UC diagram. Show it on sequence diagram, activity diagram, component diagram etc, but **NOT** on UC.